# Need to break after exception is handled

Tags: c#, exception

I have built an app in C#, where I have to break just after an exception is caught. I used `return`, but it returned to the module which called this module and continued execution. What should be done?

My code looks likes this:

```
class a
{
    b bee=new b{};
    bee.read(name);
    bee.write(name);// don want this to get executed if exception is thrown
}

class b
{
    read(string name)
    {
        try{}
        catch
        {
             //caught;

             //what should be put here so that it just stops after dialog 
             // box is shown without moving to the write method?

        }    

         write(string name) {}                
    }
}
```

Comment: Your sample is incorrect and won't ever compile, please provide a valid code sample

Comment: What do you mean by `break`? Should the application exit? Or simply pause for a while?

Comment: Do you want to shut the whole application down when the exception is caught?

Comment: @Dyppl I don want to shut the app, I know that above code wont compile, its just for reference..

Comment: @Akram: Thanks for indenting and formatting the code

Comment: @Oded Break means to stop the flow of program after exception is caught

Comment: @Srikanth Yadake: so what do you mean by "breaking"?

Comment: @akram thanks for formatting , this is my first ever Q in sof.. :)

Comment: Still not clear. You want to stop execution of the method at that point?

Comment: What exactly _do_ you want to happen? The program should stop? That means it should shut down.

Comment: @Srikanth Yadake, @SharpUrBrain : "Copy Editor" badge does not matter any more .. thank you guys :)

Comment: @all :thanks for the quickest replies.. have to say this is the fastest ever forum! my app got fixed with the below answers

Comment: @Srikanth Yadake: feel free to mark the answer that you found the most useful as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample is incorrect, but let's assume that you have a **method** with this code inside:

```
void M()
{
    b bee=new b();
    bee.read(name);
    bee.write(name);// don want this to get executed if exception is thrown
}
```

If so, you have to catch exceptions in this method, not in `read` method. Like so:

```
void M()
{
    try {
        b bee=new b();
        bee.read(name);
        bee.write(name);// don want this to get executed if exception is thrown
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Proper error handling
    }

}
```

In `read` method you should not suppress exceptions. Either don't catch them at all or rethrow them (or better yet, throw a new exception with the old one being its `InnerExeption`).

If you handle exceptions in method M this way, he line `bee.write(name)` won't be executed if an exception occurs somewhere inside `bee.read(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let the exception bubble up to the calling method:

```
class A {

  public void Method() {
    B bee = new B{};
    try {
      bee.Read(name);
      bee.Write(name);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      // handle exception if needed
    }
  }

}

class B {

  public void Read(string name) {
    try{
      ...
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      // handle exception if needed
      throw;
    }
  }

  public void Write(string name) {
  }

}
```

Note: You should catch a more specific exception class if posible, instead of catching the base class Exception. The catch syntax without an excpetion parameter is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as follows

```
class a
{
   b bee = new b();
   try
   {
     bee.read(name);
     bee.write(name);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //handle error here
   }
}

class b
{
   //These are your method implementations without catching the exceptions in b
   read
   write

}
```

If you catch the exception in the method then you won't have any way of knowing the exceution state of the method without hangind some kind of error status off the method. Whether that is a boolean return or an error code that is accesible in b.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the read method return a value that means something to the caller? so the caller inspects the return from read and if it's (for example) null it doesn't call write. Alternatively your read method could return an enum value that tells the caller the condition with which the read method exited.

As another option your caller could implement an interface with a doNotProceed method, then pass itself to the read method. On exception read calls caller.doNotProceed, setting an internal variable within the caller object and this tells it to not proceed to write.

You have plenty of options

Answer (score 0):

You can use return statement or re throw the error and put another  a parent try catch , but its better you restructure your code.